# Domain and form of a composition

Tags: calculus, functions

I'm trying to do the following composition:

$f:y=\frac{s+1}{s-1}$$,$  $g:y=\sqrt{s}$

My solution:

$Dg\circ f = (-\infty;-1] \cup(1;\infty) $

$g\circ f: y= \sqrt{\frac{s+1}{s-1}}$

Is my solution correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you've done. Is there anything in particular you're not sure of?

Comment: @JohnOmielan No, I just wanted to be sure that I'm doing it right. Thanks